# dictionary database, one table vs table for each char

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very simple database contains one table `T`

```
wOrig nvarchar(50), not null
wTran nvarchar(50), not null
```

The table has +50 million rows. I execute a simple query

```
select wTran where wOrig = 'myword'
```

The query takes about 40 sec to complete. I divided the table based on the first char of wOrig and the execution time is much smaller than before (based on each table new length).
Am I missing something here? Should not the database use more efficient way to do the search, like binary search?
**My question** What changes to the database options - based on this situation - could make the search more efficient in order to keep all the data in one table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using an index.  For your query, you want an index on `wTran(wOrig)`.  Your query will be much faster:

```
create index idx_wTran_wOrig on wTran(wOrig);
```

Depending on considerations such as space and insert/update characteristics, a clustered index on `(wOrig)` or `(wOrig, wTran)` might be the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you explain more or point me to a link?

Comment: @BassemAkl . . . A good place to start is the documentation:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095(v=sql.110).aspx.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will follow the link and try this solution.

Comment: Thank you so much. It made a real difference.